# how to derive a class from another in c++?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector

I am trying to build a list of games that I have. I have a class named gameCommon

```
class gameCommon
{
public:
string name;
int price;
}
```

This is the common information all games have. Now the next part is to build another class which will hold information based on what type of game is it? (CD/DVD, Cartridge, etc.)

if CD/DVD, class will be something like this,

```
class childClassOf_gameCommon
{
public:
int NumOfDisks;
}
```

etc.But the thing is, the list itself will be inside a vector of the parent class. Something like `vector<gameCommon*>`. So how do I derive `childClassOf_gameCommon` so that the list of `vector<gameCommon*>` will hold the attributes of `gameCommon` and depending on the type, additional information like `numOfDisks`.. Sorry for being confusing.

Comment: You should honestly start with a good C++ book. `class DerivedGame : GameCommon`

Comment: "child" is a terrible metaphor for a derived class...

Comment: I second @Joe with recommending [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: You may want to consider using a database rather than writing your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
class Derived : public gameCommon
{
public:
    int NumOfDisks;
    // ....
```

A pointer of type `gameCommon*` can legitimately point to a `Derived`.

(But as the comments point out, you should try to learn a bit more theory.  Learning by doing is good, but you need to know more of the basics, or you'll find it an uphill struggle.)